# Short circuit evaluation assignment in python?

Tags: python

Ruby supports this:

```
name = name || "default"
```

If I try it in python:

```
name = name or "default"
```

Interpreter reports:

```
NameError: name 'name' is not defined
```

What is the equivalent of the short circuit evaluation assignment in python?

Comment: This works in ruby due to the [insane ``x == x`` where ``x`` is undefined being ``nil``](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat). That's a rare stupidity in Ruby. Javascript is... well, let's not go there.

Comment: @Lattyware Ruby supports even a shorter version of the above with `name ||= "default"`

Comment: Don't know about ruby, but javascript does not support this: `node -e 'foo=foo||1'` => `ReferenceError: foo is not defined`

Comment: Oh, don't get me wrong, I'm not expert on Ruby - I've barely used the language (Python suits my preferences better), just one thing I'd heard of before.

Comment: @thg435 I tried it in console in chrome with name and `name = name || "default"` gave `"default"` but now I see it works only for `name` variable. Strange.

Comment: @thg435 It worked with name because `window.name` is `""` thanks for pointing this out, so it work because it was already defined.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
name = globals()['name'] if 'name' in globals() else 'default'
```

or, more succinctly:

```
name = globals().get('name','default')
```

Substitute `locals()` inside functions.

---

Possibly it would be better to just `try/except`:

```
try:
   name
except NameError:
   name = 'default'
```

---

As a side note, I would never use either of these idioms in my code.  (Of course, I wouldn't use the other idioms from Javascript or Ruby that you mentioned).  I'd make sure my variables were declared to the default values at the outset and then change them to non-default values as the need arises.

Comment: How often do you come across dynamically generated locals or globals? *Normally* (in Ruby and JavaScript too) you have just stumbled on a programming error.. At least Python raises an exception!

Comment: +1 for the exception - that is the correct way to deal with this. (Although in most cases, you should probably be using a dictionary). The other method, I would not use.

Comment: @MartijnPieters -- I come across it in `bash` pretty frequently where undefined variables are just empty.  I never come across it in python, but the only python code I work with is my own ... I don't know what other people do other than as I've inferred by hanging around SO long enough.

Comment: @Lattyware -- I wouldn't use either of these -- I'd make sure all my variables were declared before I set off, but these were the most straight forward interpretation of the other languages I could come up with.

Comment: Undefined variables being empty is a terrible idea, it just masks the (99% of the time) error until later on. The common case (and the case that is harder to fix) is you want to know it's undefined and deal with it, so Python is (sanely) optimised for that case.

Comment: @mgilson Of course, as I say, this looks like a case where the asker should be using a dictionary, or some other similar data structure.

Comment: Note, you can just use `globals().setdefault('name','default')` for your first example -- totally agree this is a bad idea in general though

Comment: @VaughnCato -- Don't use `setdefault`.  It wouldn't be guaranteed to work with `locals` in a function.  But I've updated with a `name = globals().get('name','default')`

Answer (score 21):

If you actually defined `name` it'd work:

```
name = None
name = name or 'default'
```

The short-circuiting is independent from actually having to define your variables. Generally, `name` has been pulled from *somewhere* but is an empty (falsy) value:

```
name = somefunction('name') or 'default'
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a horrible, horrible idea, but ...

```
name = globals().get("name", locals().get("name", "default"))
```

... will do what you want (while leaving you in the dark as to whether you now have a global or local variable), and is ugly enough to hopefully put you off trying it.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
try:
    name = "some value"
except NameError:
    name = "default value"
```